# How to position a large number of elements using flexbox without resorting to position: absolute?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I'm doing a landing page for testing flexbox technology. I ran into a problem: I can't figure out how to position a large number of elements without resorting to crutches like this:

[image: Complicated layout for flexbox]

Also without resorting to position:absolute, because there will be inaccuracies in the margins or it will take a very long time to calculate these margins.

This is what I currently have:

[image: Current progress using position absolute]

On the second one, I indicated how I see one of the working implementation options: organize two columns in footer and make them flex-direction: column.

Here is my markup:

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer__logo">
    <img src="icons/Logo.svg" alt="logo" class="logo__img">
    <p class="logo__text"> PETWORLD </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer__input">
    <label for="email" class="text">Updates right to your Inbox</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="submit__text text">
  </div>

  <div class="footer__privacy">
    <p class="privacy__text"> Text</p>
    <p class="privacy__text"> Text</p>
    <p class="privacy__text"> Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer__menu">
    <!-- x3 колонки текста -->
    <div class="menu__text">
      <p class="text">Text</p>
      <p class="text">Text</p>
      <p class="text">Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer__social">
    <img src="icons/Socials icons.svg" alt="" class="logo__img">
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: we cant see your images (we can copy them into the url but they're not embedded i mean). Also, it's hard to decipher what the actual issue is. I'm confused as to what you need help with. Also, BEM being violated is not necessarily a crutch (dont get too attached to any single way of doing things, there's always edge cases). theres only so many ways you can organize content. and there may be ways to not violate BEM if you re-think your 'components'

Comment: I have a lot of elements that I don't understand how to arrange them "flexbox technology" correctly. maybe I'm complicating things and it's worth doing the way I know?

sorry for the images, I thought they would be attached as hyperlinks :)

Comment: Hi Omar. Your markup doesn't seem consistent with the current progress image you've provided, it might also help if you included the CSS you've tried. In order to achieve your desired outcome you will need many flexboxes nested within each other, there should be no reason to use position absolute.

Comment: Hi, Zach. Yes, you're right. I will now make css as I see it, I think there will be more substantive communication :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to move away from BEM a bit and divided my footer into two visual components.

What came out in the end can be viewed below:
https://codepen.io/productomar/pen/ZEvNQjG

------------------**HTML**---------------------

```
<div class="container__footer">
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="first__half">
                    <div class="footer__logo">
                        <img src="icons/Logo.svg" alt="logo" class="logo__img">
                        <p class="logo__text"> PETWORLD </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="footer__input">
                        <label for="email" class="text">Updates right to your Inbox</label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="placeholder__text">
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="submit__text text">
                    </div>

                    <div class="footer__privacy">
                        <p class="privacy__text"> © PETWORLD 2022</p>
                        <p class="privacy__text"> Privacy policy</p>
                        <p class="privacy__text"> Terms of use</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="second__half">
                    <div class="footer__menu">
                        <div class="menu__text">
                            <p class="text menu__b" style="font-weight: 600;">Our story</p>
                            <p class="text__item text">FAQ</p>
                            <p class="text__item text">Contact</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu__text">
                            <p class="text menu__b" style="font-weight: 600;">Pet care</p>
                            <p class="text__item text">Treatments</p>
                            <p class="text__item text">Health</p>
                            <p class="text__item text">Hygiene </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu__text">
                            <p class="text menu__b" style="font-weight: 600;">Shop</p>
                            <p class="text__item text">Pet Food</p>
                            <p class="text__item text">Toys</p>
                            <p class="text__item text">Accessories</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="footer__social">
                        <img src="icons/Socials icons.svg" alt="logo__social" class="logo__social">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
```

------------------**CSS**---------------------

```
        /* Первая часть футера */
    .first__half {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .footer {
        display: flex;
        padding: 70px 80.5px;
    }
    
    .footer__logo {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .logo__text {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .footer__input {
        margin-top: 75px;
    }
    
    label {
        display: block;
    }
    
    input[type="email"] {
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-top: 12px;
    }
    
    .placeholder__text {
        padding-top: 11px;
        padding-bottom: 11px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 71px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #2D2D2D;
    }
    
    .submit__text {
        padding: 11px 31.5px;
        background-color: #3366FF;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .footer__privacy {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 33px;
    }
    
    .privacy__text {
        margin-right: 30px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    .privacy__text:nth-child(3) {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    /* Вторая часть футера */
    
    .second__half {
        margin-left: 233px;
    }
    
    .footer__menu {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .menu__text {
        margin-right: 60px;
    }
    
    .text__item {
        padding-top: 16px;
    }
    
    .menu__text:nth-child(3) {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    
    .footer__social {
        margin-top: 99px;
    }
    
    .logo__social {
        margin-left: 237px;
    }
```